# Prevent make from removing source files generated from the .def files

Tags: c, linux, bash, makefile

I do not exactly know how `.def` files are being used and what are they though I would like make to not remove source files generated with the same name as the `.def` files after creating their corresponding object files. Is there anyway to do that?

More specifically, I am working on [bash-4.1](https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-4.1.tar.gz) and I see many `.def` files like `builtins/suspend.def` and after executing `make`, `suspend.o` gets generated using a `suspend.c`, which does not exist before issuing make, but also gets removed right after the compile command. How can I stop make from removing these source files?

Comment: There must be something in your `Makefile` that instructs `make` to remove files. Please show the `Makefile` in your question.

Comment: I cannot copy the whole Makefile as it passes the limit of 30000 characters. I updated the question with a link to the `tar` file. If you extract that you get the Makefile in the root of the directory.

Comment: Try adding `.SECONDARY: builtins/%.def` in case it gets removed due to [an implicit chain](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Chained-Rules.html). If it does not help, you must inspect the whole Makefile to find the offending command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file `builtins/Makefile.in` in the Tar file linked from the question you see a references to `suspend` in

```
DEFSRC =  $(srcdir)/alias.def $(srcdir)/bind.def $(srcdir)/break.def \
# ...
          $(srcdir)/source.def $(srcdir)/suspend.def $(srcdir)/test.def \
# ...
```

and

```
OFILES = builtins.o \
# ...
        pushd.o read.o return.o set.o setattr.o shift.o source.o \
        suspend.o test.o times.o trap.o type.o ulimit.o umask.o \
        wait.o getopts.o shopt.o printf.o getopt.o bashgetopt.o complete.o
```

The `Makefile.in` contains these pattern rules:

```
# How to make a .o file from a .def file.
.def.o:
        $(RM) $@
        ./$(MKBUILTINS) $(DIRECTDEFINE) $<
        $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $*.c || ( $(RM) $*.c ; exit 1 )
        $(RM) $*.c

# How to make a .c file from a .def file.
.def.c:
        $(RM) $@
        ./$(MKBUILTINS) $(DIRECTDEFINE) $<

# default rule for making a .o file from a .c file
.c.o:
        $(RM) $@
        $(CC) -c $(CCFLAGS) $<
```

As there is only a file `suspend.def`and a  file `suspend.c` is not explicitly mentioned, the object `suspend.o` will be created by the rule `.def.o:` which contains

```
        $(RM) $*.c
```

as the last command.

You can remove or comment this line.
The rule will also remove the corresponding `.c` file if the compilation fails. If necessary you can remove this as well.

Note that this modification may change the behavior of subsequent builds, because then the existing `.c` files will be considered by `make`.

**Additional information as requested:**

As you can see from the `Makefile` rule, the `.def` files will be processed using

```
        ./$(MKBUILTINS) $(DIRECTDEFINE) $<
```

This will call `$(MKBUILTINS)` with additional arguments `$(DIRECTDEFINE)`, which is defined as `-D $(srcdir)`, and the dependency file (`$<`), i.e. the matching `.def` file. `MKBUILTINS` is defined as `mkbuiltins$(EXEEXT)` which probably is `mkbuiltins` or `mkbuiltins.exe`.

From the context I can guess, that `mkbuiltins` will create a corresponding `.c` file from the `.def` file.

As again you can see from the `Makefile`, `mkbuiltins` is build from `mkbuiltins.c` using `config.h`. Check the source code or ask in `bash` related forums what exactly `mkbuiltins` will do.

Comment: Thank you so much. Could you please also give some information on the `.def` files and how source files are being generated?